Subtract 2 voltages and amplify using 1 op-amp
I am designing circuit that senses voltage of multiple batteries in series. The circuits in the picture uses 2 LM358 op-amps, and does the operation((Bat3+ - Bat2+)-2.5)*20/6.8, to fully use the ADC range(0-5V). I wonder if it is possible to do the same thing on just one op-amp? If it is not possible, any suggestion for how to sense the voltage?
Thank you!

Edit:
Thanks for the comment, I didn't realize the op-amp is upside down. The simulator runs find because I wired it correctly in the simulator, but I have no idea why PCB outputs some reading, probably it is not working properly and I thought that was an error.
The following picture is the full schematic.

The batteries are Li-ion batteries, and I am using 5V ADC.
The following picture is a edited version.

The circuit works in simulator, any suggestion is welcomed.

You need to simulate that circuit and, when you do, you'll realize why I suggested it.

Please add a reference to the source of your image.

If you want to check if the series batteries get unbalanced (compare their voltages), then that's not correct.  You should do:  diff = (2*BAT2 - BAT3) * amplification.  Or what is the same: (BAT2 - BAT3/2) * amplification.   Provided that BAT3 is above BAT2 respect GND.  And that can be done with one opamp, one that is rail-to-rail, or at least fitting your voltage ranges.

Thank you for your advice. This circuit works on simulator and on PCB. But I still didn't get why"diff = (2BAT2 - BAT3) * amplification" could tell me if batteries get inbalanced. For example, if battery 1 is 3.7v, bat 2 is 4v and bat3 is 4.2v,  (2BAT2 - BAT3) will give me 3.5v... Could you please explain more in detail? Thank you.

@zyx, With 2 batteries to simplify.  If battery 1 is 3.7v, bat 2 is 4v and they are in series, then batt1 is 3.7V respect GND, and batt2 is 7.7V respect GND.  Then: 2*3.7 - 7.7 = -0.3V.  Then you can shift and amplify as needed. And if you divide instead of multiply, a simple voltage divider would do it. Your method would be also correct if you do something before to get the relative voltage of each battery, maybe it's done. You should simulate your circuit.

@Gos, Thank you I get your point.

@xyz - Are you sure this thing works at all with the first op amp having positive feedback? Why not show the entire schematics to get a picture of what is what? How many batteries are in series? What type of batteries are we talking here? LiPo/LiIon? If that is the case a gain of 1 would be sufficient for a 5V ADC and a single opamp can manage that.

@Raonoke Thanks for pointing out, pls see edited quesion

@xyz - The common mode range of the LM358 does not include the upper rail (VCC) which means the U21.1 buffer in the edited version will not work as intended.

@Raonake- Thanks, probably I have to feed VCC into V4. Any other suggestion for this circuit?

@xyz - Yes, remove U21.1. The battery is drained anyway because of R1/R4/R5, the extra buffer stage for VCC is redundant. Make the mentioned resistors e.g. 10x larger and connect R1 directly to VCC. Maybe consider doing the same to all the other resistors to cut down the overall battery (VCC) current drain.

@Raonoke, Very valuable advice, Thank you.

Forgive me for addressing your likely ultimate problem rather than your proximate question.
If you're designing a Battery Management System for a Li-ion battery, be aware that your circuit will over-discharge the cells in little time and damage them permanently. Use instead a LI-ion BMS front end IC.

It only draws ~1uA from the cells (less than their self-discharge current)
It draws current from the power supply only when enabled (yours draws current all the time)
It measures the voltage across each cell (not the voltage to ground)
It outputs a reading (a digital value) rather than an analog voltage that you then need to convert to a number.
It has an accuracy and resolution of 1 mV or better (yours has about 30 mV)

Linear Technology and Texas Instruments are among the companies that offer these ICs.

Thank you for your advice. Yes I am designing a BMS, but just for fun so I wish not to buy something readily available. You mentioned this circuit will over-discharge cells very quickly, is it because the resistors like R3, R4 and R12, if neglect the current op-amps are consuming? If I want to improve it, should I find the bias current of op-amp and use the largest resistor allowed for my tolerance? Thank you.

"is it because the resistors like R3, R4 and R12,"> Yes. " If I want to improve it," don't bother: it's a non-starter. Do as I said: use a Li-ion front-end IC. You still get to design a BMS, but at least you have  decent chance of succeeding.

The circuit you shared uses two op-amps (LM358) to perform the operation:
Vout = ((VBAT3 - VBAT2)-2.5V)
This offsets the voltage difference by 2.5V and scales it to match the ADC range (0-5V).
Can it be done with 1 Op-Amp?
No, this particular operation cannot be done using only one op-amp because:

You need the first op-amp for differential voltage sensing (to subtract the battery voltages).
The second op-amp is used to shift and amplify the voltage for the ADC.

Suggestions -

Instrumentation Amplifier: Use a dedicated instrumentation amplifier to handle the differential voltage sensing in a more compact way.
Precision Rail-to-Rail Op-Amps: A more accurate op-amp might reduce the need for complex configurations but will still require two op-amps or similar circuitry for offset and gain adjustment.


Your "because" explanation does not provide any proof.  It only explains how the current pair of op-amps are used.
